# Replace Unknown values in factor

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, missing-data

I was searching how to replace in my dataset missing values what are sorted into "unknown"
all unknown values are in factors columns..
for example i have marital status with atributes married,single divorced and unknown.. Im searching a way how to replace "unknown" not to delete.. others factors are only yes,no,unknown.

```
bank$marital <- factor(c('married','divorced','married','unknown','single'))
```

i want only to replace "unknown" with for example "single"

```
bank$marital = bank$marital.fillna(bank$marital.mode[yes],inplace = True)

bank$marital[is.na(bank$marital)]<-mean(bank$marital,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I cant use mean because its factor ...
But i could not  find a right way how to replace "unknown" values in factors

Comment: Clearly there is no mean of c('married','divorced','married','unknown','single'). You have to chose which value you would like to replace NA with. My guess is that 'unknown' would be the right choice. So `bank$marital[is.na(bank$marital)] <- "unknown")`?

Comment: I have no NA values.. NA values are saved as "unknown" and i need to replace "unknown" values with for example with 'x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

See [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/factor/).

```r
bank <- data.frame(marital = as.factor(c('married','divorced','married','unknown','single')))

levels(bank$marital) <- c(levels(bank$marital), "x")    # add new level

bank$marital[ bank$marital == "unknown" ] <- "x"

bank$marital
#> [1] married  divorced married  x        single  
#> Levels: divorced married single unknown x
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes this one . Thank you

Comment: Is there any function like a "mean" in numeric atributes what could help split "unknow" values to married,divorced,single?

Comment: I think you would need to do this 'manually' either by randomly assigning one of these values or by figuring out the number of values to replace and then choosing the 'correct' distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like below?

```
f <- type.convert(f, as.is = TRUE)
replace(f,is.na(f),mean(f,na.rm = TRUE))
# [1] 1.000 2.775 4.000 3.000 3.100 2.775
```

**Dummy Data**

```
f <- factor(c(1,NA,4,3,3.1,NA))
```

Comment: I cant post a photo but. https://ctrlv.link/dlhO this is what values is under a marital column for example. there is no NA value because its sorted into unknown value. And i want to replace "unknown" value with for example "married"